# Why does Windows Explorer keep opening folders in new windows on Windows 2008 Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-explorer

I just ran Windows Update on a new Windows 2008 Standard Edition SP2 64-bit server today. Since then Windows Explorer keeps opening folders in new windows when I double click on them.

I've double check that the folder options are correct:

`Organize -> Folder and Search Options -> Browse folders -> Open each folder in the same window` - this is selected.

I've googled around and there was suggestion that changing the following registry keys `Default` value should work:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore\command`
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open\command`

Changing from:
`%SystemRoot%\Explorer.exe /separate,/e,/idlist,%I,%L`
To:
`%SystemRoot%\Explorer.exe /same,/e,/idlist,%I,%L` or `%SystemRoot%\Explorer.exe /e,/idlist,%I,%L`

I've even rebooted the machine and tried different accounts but the behaviour remains the same.

I've inspected each update but nothing jumps out as being a change to the behaviour of Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was related to the IE8 update provided by Windows Update. Removing that reverted the server's Explorer behaviour to normal again.